# matplotlib - Keyboard shortcuts to pan left/right/up/down

Tags: event-handling, matplotlib, keyboard-shortcuts

In `matplotlib`, is there a keyboard alternative to dragging a plot with the left mouse click for panning in the four directions?

Reason is, apart from the fact that it seems like an obvious keyboard shortcut, I'm printing the `xdata` value every time I left-click. It would be useful to drag without clicking the plot.

Otherwise, is there a way to connect to a double-click event? That way I could print my value only on that event. For the moment I have solved by printing on right-click.

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Comment: No, I didn't unfortunately.

Comment: See update to my answer please

Answer (score 2):

```
def on_dbl_click(event):
    if event.dblclick:
        print event.x, event.y

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_dbl_click)
```

You just need to test if the event has `dblcilck` set [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.MouseEvent)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I added a "ctrl+c" shortcut to a matplotlib figure. Any figure created with the function below will copy a picture of the figure to the clipboard through "ctrl+c".

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt4       import QtGui
def figure(num = None):
    """Creates and returns a matplotlib figure and adds a 'ctrl+c' shortcut that copies figure to clipboard"""
    def on_ctrl_c_click(event):        
        if event.key == 'ctrl+c' or event.key == 'ctrl+C':
            QtGui.QApplication.clipboard().setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.grabWidget(fig.canvas))
    fig = plt.figure(num)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_ctrl_c_click)    
    return fig
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple function to allow panning in all 4 directions using the arrow keys.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def pan_nav(event):

    ax_tmp = plt.gca()
    if event.key == 'left':
        lims = ax_tmp.get_xlim()
        adjust = (lims[1] - lims[0]) * 0.9
        ax_tmp.set_xlim((lims[0] - adjust, lims[1] - adjust))
        plt.draw()
    elif event.key == 'right':
        lims = ax_tmp.get_xlim()
        adjust = (lims[1] - lims[0]) * 0.9
        ax_tmp.set_xlim((lims[0] + adjust, lims[1] + adjust))
        plt.draw()
    elif event.key == 'down':
        lims = ax_tmp.get_ylim()
        adjust = (lims[1] - lims[0]) * 0.9
        ax_tmp.set_ylim((lims[0] - adjust, lims[1] - adjust))
        plt.draw()
    elif event.key == 'up':
        lims = ax_tmp.get_ylim()
        adjust = (lims[1] - lims[0]) * 0.9
        ax_tmp.set_ylim((lims[0] + adjust, lims[1] + adjust))
        plt.draw()

fig = plt.figure()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', pan_nav)
plt.plot(1, 1, 'ko')   # plot something
```